# Storyboard UI not updating while working on storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I m facing very strange issue in that I have one project which was created in Xcode 8.3.2 and swift 3 and now I have updated the code with swift 4 and using latest Xcode 9.2 all other changes I have made and app is working fine in simulator and device

Main Problem:
 - When I open storyboard so it load properly and if I m making any changes in any viewcontroller(Interface builder) so it is not reflecting in that viewcontroller(Interface builder) after quit storyboard and reload so my change are showing so I have to do this all the time for every single changes I made in the storyboard

I have tried to search to whole stack and also many other links still not find a solutions so let me know the solutions or your suggestions

Note:- I can not take new storyboard cause I have already design too many screens so.

Comment: its happening because seems like your main Storyboard is having many VC in it and while saving Xcode Fails , need to manage Project create separate Storyboard file and take some VC in new Storyboard , I had faced same issue , I solved creating new Storyboard i.e Taking some load of Main storyboard in new Storyboard

Comment: @iOSGeek thanks for your comment , that solutions i know but i can not move all view Controller to new storyboard cause there are too many screens around 40.

Comment: Just take those VC who need to be Modified , This issue occurred to me When I had many Vc in single Storyboard , else try one thing in Activity monitor while you are editing Stop processes names as ibtoold  when you are done with some changes Refresh storyboard and this time do not stop ibtoold, hope it helps

Comment: @iOSGeek ibtoold not showing in my activity monitor

Comment: you should use more then one storyboard if you have around 40 storyboard. Multiple storyboard easy and fast to process. Lots of View Controller in Storyboard might not update. Check if Refresh all Views in editor works for you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers and comments  i found the problem so here is the description.

i have used google maps pod and due to that IB Designable of that class used view are not render and creating problem in storyboard.

here is my work around: remove the reference of GMSMapview temporary and start working after my work i will re-reference it.

Answer (score 3):

I have facing same issue. Please do as below.

> 1. Go to > Project directory.
> 2. Select ProjectName.xcodeproj and go to show package content as below as per below image.

[image]

> 3. Delete `xcuserdata` folder, You can show in below image.

[image]

> 3. Remove derive data from project.
> 4. Just clean and Build...Happy coding...

Comment: Tried but still problem persist.. any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers explain why this keeps happening to me. Turns out my issue was turning on iCloud Desktop syncing and having the project directory on the Desktop. Moving the project to the Downloads folder or turning off iCloud Desktop syncing seems to have fix this issue.

Comment: you are right cause this issue is not common, that's  why i have posted my solutions so it might help others and thanks for posting your answer ;

Answer (score 0):

To refresh Storyboard

1. Open Storyboard
2. Click on editor
3. Refresh all views

Hope this will help you